# Using jq on a large json file (50GB)

Tags: json, linux, bigdata, jq

I want to use jq on a 50GB file. Needless to say the machines memory can't handle it. It's running out of memory.

I tried several options including --stream but it didn't help. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ? And how to fix it

```
jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))' file.json |   jq -cr .data[] >> out.json
```

The file contains data like this:

```
{"data":[{"id":"id1","value":"value1"},{"id":"id2","value":"value2"},{"id":"id3","value":"value3"}...]}
```

i want to read each value of the array in the data field and put it line by line in another file. such as below

```
{"id":"id1","value":"value1"}
{"id":"id2","value":"value2"}
{"id":"id3","value":"value3"}
```

Right now the command is running out of memory and gets killed.

Comment: As soon as you call `fromstream` you're asking jq to read the stream and make a data structure in memory from it. Using `--stream` isn't useful unless you somehow filter the stream down to something more manageable before calling `fromstream` (if you ever do so at all). As for advice on how to do that... it would help if you described the actual problem you're trying to solve in more detail.

Comment: How to fix what? What are your error messages / misbehavior / example of content / example of needed output?

Comment: Is your goal to extract the `data` key from the top-level object in the original? Is the value found there small enough to fit in RAM? Are you trying to do something else?

Comment: How do you mean the machine "can't handle it."?  Do you get an error?  Is it slow?

Comment: "I want to use jq on a 50GB file" -- isn't that the wrong tool for this job? why does it have to be jq? I generally think that any problem that is stated as "want to use X to solve problem Y" is putting the cart before the horse. It's very rare that the tool to use is already dictated.

Comment: @ChristianFritz what other tool can get the job done? 
And its running out of memory

Comment: I would look at the "big data" tools. I haven't kept up with their development, but maybe look at hadoop or apache spark. Given that the data is an array you can probably also just use mongodb. Look at the `mongoimport` command for loading the file into mongo. Once it's in, everything else will be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

For your example, the following would suffice:

```
jq -cn --stream 'fromstream( inputs|(.[0] |= .[2:]) | select(. != [[]]) )'
```

If you only wanted the .data array to be itemized, replace `inputs` in the above by:

```
inputs|select(first|first=="data")
```

For the record, you could also use gojq (the Go implementation of jq) in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 1):

> what other tool can get the job done?

[jm](https://GitHub.com/pkoppstein/jm), a command-line wrapper I wrote for “JSON Machine”, is very easy to use and often more economical than jq’s streaming parser.  In the present case, to itemize .data, you would write:

```
jm —-pointer '/data'
```

Or similarly, using the Python-based script in the same repository:

```
jm.py -i data.item file.json
```

Assuming there is just one top-level key, then another alternative in this particular case would be:

```
jstream -d 2 <  file.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your large file contains a lot on json objects, you can process them one by one and extract the field `.data[]`.

This way, the memory consumption is limited by the size of the largest json from the input and not by the sum of the sizes of all json inputs.

Or is your problem that a *single* json object is so large that the memory is insufficient?

```sh
echo '
{ "key":"A1", "property":"A2", "data":[1,2,3] }{"key":"B1","property":"B2","data":[4,5,6]}
{ 
   "key":"C1", 
   "property":"C2", 
   "data":[7,8,9] 
}' | jq -cr '.data[]'
```

result

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```