# jq performance for very large file

Tags: json, filter, bigdata, jq

I'm trying to use jq to parse the wikidata dump, which is approximately 1.5Tb of a single JSON array (each item within the array is separated by a newline though). I have some complex filtering operations to extract the data I want, but it takes a loooooong time to process and I'm wondering if there's a better way to speed it up, either if my filter below can be optimized, or if I should change the way I'm running jq.

From what I can tell I have a couple options, but I'm limited by memory

- strip away the outer [] and treat it like ndjson file, stream one at a time into jq (or batch them)
- pass it in using the `--stream` flag, however I can't really grok how that changes the filter and it states it runs slower but saves memory

Given a single item looking like this (as an example):

```json
{
  "id": "Q60",
  "type": "item",
  "aliases": {
    "en": [
      {
        "language": "en",
        "value": "NYC"
      },
      {
        "language": "en",
        "value": "New York"
      }
    ],
    "fr": [
      {
        "language": "fr",
        "value": "New York City"
      },
      {
        "language": "fr",
        "value": "NYC"
      }
    ]
  },
  "labels": {
    "en": {
      "language": "en",
      "value": "New York City"
    }
  },
  "claims": {
    "P625": [
      {
        "id": "q60$f00c56de-4bac-e259-b146-254897432868",
        "mainsnak": {
          "snaktype": "value",
          "property": "P625",
          "datatype": "globe-coordinate",
          "datavalue": {
            "value": {
              "latitude": 40.67,
              "longitude": -73.94,
              "altitude": null,
              "precision": 0.00027777777777778,
              "globe": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q2"
            },
            "type": "globecoordinate"
          }
        },
        "type": "statement",
        "rank": "normal",
        "references": [
          {
            "hash": "7eb64cf9621d34c54fd4bd040ed4b61a88c4a1a0",
            "snaks": {
              "P143": [
                {
                  "snaktype": "value",
                  "property": "P143",
                  "datatype": "wikibase-item",
                  "datavalue": {
                    "value": {
                      "entity-type": "item",
                      "id": "Q328",
                      "numeric-id": 328
                    },
                    "type": "wikibase-entityid"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            "snaks-order": [
              "P143"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm interesting in:

- extracting the id as a number
- only elements with type = "item"
- only if they have an English label
- also extract any English aliases
- only those that don't have a claim of key "P31" which contains a datavalue of Q13442814
- output as tsv

My current filter looks like this:

`.[] | select((.type == "item") and (.labels | has("en")) and (.claims.P31 // [] | map(.mainsnak.datavalue.value.id != "Q13442814") | all)) | (.id|ltrimstr("Q")) as $id | .labels["en"].value, (.aliases["en"] // [] | map(.value))[] | [$id, .] | @tsv`

Which returns

```
60\tNew York City
60\tNYC
60\tNew York
```

Comment: For speed and economy, splat the top-level array using jstream, jm, or jm.py as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68180419/using-jq-on-a-large-json-file-50gb, and then apply your jq filter.

Comment: @errorline1 : Interesting stuff. Please post run times for the various versions you try. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The `--stream` flag parses the input by breaking it down into a stream of arrays, which can be processes before reading the entire input has ended. These arrays contain either one or two items. The first one is the current path of the parser (also represented as array of strings for field names, or numbers for array indices), and the second one if present is the scalar value at the current path. The arrays where the second item is missing can be used for backtracking on the document tree, if you want to keep track with the parser.

Typically, you want to use two more functions in combination with `--stream`:

One is `truncate_stream` which simply cuts off a given number (provided as input) of items from the current path array. This enables you to process starting from a given depth, which you can use with `1` instead of iterating through the top level array using `.[]`.

The other one is `fromstream` which takes a stream of such broken-down arrays, and each time it reads a backtracking item on top level (which will occur more often if the input was truncated) it re-assembles its current buffer to a (truncated) item from the original structure.

That said, if a single item of your original input array *does* fit into your memory, you can use `fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))` using `--stream` and the `-n` flag (for `inputs`), followed by your original filter (after `.[] |`) on the unstripped input array to access its items as you did before but without loading the whole document into memory:

```bash
jq -rn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs)) | select(…) | … | @tsv'
```

If a single item is still too big for your memory, you can further optimize the reduction by processing the broken-down items as they come in, thus after `truncate_stream` but before (i.e. still inside) `fromstream`. Typically, these steps include filters using `select` on either the path item or the value item (including tests if the current input *has* a value item, see above), as well as using `truncate_stream` more often and/or with higher depth values. To this end, you could look at what the (streamed) input looks like using just `jq -cn --stream '1|truncate_stream(inputs)'` (preferably with a pager like `less`), and examine which of these items unnecessarily blow up your input, then identify their features, and cut them off before re-assembling the items with `fromstream`.

```bash
jq -rn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs) | select(… .[0] … .[1] …)) | …'
```